# Mailgun email validation in C#

Tags: c#, validation, email, mailgun

I am trying to verify an email using a MailgunAPI in C#. My problem is - regardless of whether an email is valid or not, I am still getting response.Content = "{\"error\":\"not found\"}"
And it is really hard to say whether the validation URL is wrong (got it from [here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-email-validation.html#example)) or the actual email was not found.

```
var request = new RestRequest();
request.AddParameter("domain", domain, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.Method = Method.POST;
request.Resource = "/address/validate";
request.AddParameter("address", item);
var response = client.Execute(request);
dynamic content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
if (content.error != null)
{
     Console.Out.WriteLine(content.error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are making a request using 'POST' method.  Switch to 'GET' method. `request.Method = Method.GET;`

GET requires parameters to be appended to URL string. So, you might need to update the way you are sending in parameters or the `RestRequest` class might handle that for you.